# Cláusula GROUP BY en ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Soy algo nuevo en el lenguaje SQL y se me presentó el siguiente inconveniente:

- Requiero utilizar la cláusula GROUP BY para extraer registros duplicados en Base de datos. La información que se presenta es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que estoy utilizando:

```
SELECT NUMERO_ENMASCARADO, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY NUMERO_ENMASCARADO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

La cual devuelve lo siguiente:

```
NUMERO_ENMASCARADO | COUNT(*)
___________________|_________
5492301839203      | 2
5492*****9203      | 2
6478902134210      | 2
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que agrupe 5492301839203 y 5492*****9203? Pues son realmente el mismo número, pero con otro formato.

La idea sería algo como esto:

```
NUMERO_ENMASCARADO | COUNT(*)
___________________|_________
5492*****9203      | 4
6478902134210      | 2
```

ó

```
NUMERO_ENMASCARADO | COUNT(*)
___________________|_________
5492301839203      | 4
6478902134210      | 2
```

Agradecería una respuesta, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select NUMERO_ENMASCARADO, COUNT(*) as Total
from
(
   select replace(NUMERO_ENMASCARADO, substr( NUMERO_ENMASCARADO, 5, 10), '*****') as NUMERO_ENMASCARADO
   from table
)
group by NUMERO_ENMASCARADO
having count(*) > 1
```

Se hace una **subconsulta** donde utilizando las **funciones substr** y **replace** se sustituyen los **5** dígitos del medio por la cadena **'*****'**, sobre esta **subconsulta** se hace entonces una consulta más general la cual va a agrupar por el **campo NUMERO_ENMASCARADO** obteniendo solamente las filas cuyo total es mayor que **1**. Es importante aclarar que aquí todos los valores que tenga el **campo NUMERO_ENMASCARADO** saldrán con la máscara de cinco asteriscos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda @Japv, me surge una última duda.

Si en esta ocasión el número fuese: 0005492301839203... Como podría hacer coincidir 0005492301839203 con 5492*****9203.

Es decir, como haría para eliminar los 000 para que aplique el Query?

Comment: @GNTIfy dime cual es la duda?

Comment: @GNTIfy eso es muy parecido a lo q ya tienes lo que ahora tendrias q poner seria: replace(NUMERO_ENMASCARADO, substr( NUMERO_ENMASCARADO, 1, 3), ''), es decir sustituyes los tres primeros caracteres por el caracter vacio

Comment: Muchas gracias!